# How to change dataType text to ObjectId as a input Key in Mapreduce job

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, mapreduce, reduce

I want to process mongoDB ObjectId (_id) in mapReduce job and change the datattype ObjectId to String in result.
How can I change the deafult map function. Is there a way to convert type of objectid to string?

Comment: Have you tried `String(_id)` or `_id.toString()`?

Comment: Have a look at [ObjectId.toString()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId.toString/) and [ObjectId.valueOf()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId.valueOf/). OR if you are using mongo `4.0+` [`$toString`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toString/) would also convert and `ObjectId` to string.

Comment: I have used 
 if(structureData.get("_id") instanceof ObjectId)
           structureData.put("_id", String.valueOf(plainStructureData.get("_id")));